# mysqli connection file Doesnt recoqnize prepare stement

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I'm getting an error in my php mysqli file.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in
>   C:\Users\driek\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\driekvandermeulen.nl_3.0\php\main\contact1.php:20
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Users\driek\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\driekvandermeulen.nl_3.0\php\main\contact1.php(33):
>   writeDatabase('dsgd', 'Lorem@lorem.nl', 'gf', 'awesrdtfgh') #1 {main}
>   thrown in
>   C:\Users\driek\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\driekvandermeulen.nl_3.0\php\main\contact1.php
>   on line 20

It doesnt recocnize the prepare statement on line 20, But I dont see anything wrong with it.

```
    function dbConnect(){
        $servername = "localhost";                                          // Localhost stays untouched
        $username = "dbUser";                                               // Username of the MySQL database user
        $password = "R4b3Eg5Jt4Y9GKqB";                                         // Password of the MySQL database user
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);                  // Create connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {                                                 // Check connection
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        echo "Connected successfully";
        return;
    }

    function writeDatabase($p_sName,$p_sEmailAddress,$p_sSubject,$p_sMailContent){
       $conn = dbConnect();

    // -------------------- prepare and bind --------------------------------
        //$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `driekvandermeulen.tbl_emailcontacts` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt = $conn->prepare();
        $stmt->bind_param($p_sName,$p_sEmailAddress,$p_sSubject,$p_sMailContent);

                $stmt->execute(); // Actual save into the database
    }
```

Comment: try say `return $conn` in your function

Comment: Using this function will result in "Too many connections" error. there must be no such function at all

Answer (score 3):

You return nothing from your `dbConnect()` function. So assigning the result from `dbConnect()` to a variable will yield to `null`.

`$conn = dbConnect();` This line will result in `$conn = null;`.

You should try returning the connection object from your `dbConnect()` function:

```
function dbConnect(){
    $servername = "localhost";                                          // Localhost stays untouched
    $username = "dbUser";                                               // Username of the MySQL database user
    $password = "R4b3Eg5Jt4Y9GKqB";                                         // Password of the MySQL database user
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);                  // Create connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {                                                 // Check connection
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    return $conn;  // <------------------ Check this
}
```

Comment: Feel free to rephrase the comment I added that points the modification in the function using your own style

Comment: Good one on pointing out the corrected line. Will do this in advance. I will leave it like this.

Comment: Using this function will result in "Too many connections" error. It puts the answer under the "Fixing one issue, creating five" category.

Comment: Well, i am not "creating" new issues. It is just the following one in the chain. It is not that my answer will be creating new issues. If my answer would be actually giving him the `dbConnect()` function THEN i would be creating an issue. I merely fixed his syntactical issue. Of course i agree the way it is written is the optimal solution. But that is out of the scope of this question. Although it can be recommended to the person asking the question.